# Red Laser and Photoelectric Threshold Frequency

Tags: laser, photoelectric-effect

My red 650nm laser seems to always produce voltage when shined onto a solar cell. But I have read that red light is below the photoelectric effect threshold. Is the threshold much lower now due to new materials???? Looked on web for answers and did find that semiconductors have lowest threshold. Is it common now for red light to be above the threshold. Please see photos below:[image: Ambient Lighting][image: Laser Added]

Answer (score 1):

The **photoelectric** effect is different from the **photovoltaic** effect. You are thinking about the former, but solar cells are based on the latter. That explains your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the info Steve. I'll post some details that I found on the web thanks to your answer. Too long to post in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steve's answer I gathered this info from the web.

Relationship Between Energy and Wavelength

The relationship between the energy of a photon and the wavelength of light is inverse; as the wavelength of light increases, energy decreases. In the visible light spectrum, the energy of photons ranges from roughly 1.65 eV to 3.1 eV. The corresponding wavelengths of these energies are 750 and 400 nanometers, respectively. These wavelengths correspond to the red and violet ends of the spectrum of visible light.

Energy Required for Solar Cells

A typical silicon solar cell requires 1.1 eV in order for electrons to flow out of the cell and through the circuitry of the solar panel system. This 1.1 eV of energy corresponds to photons in the infrared range of the spectrum with a wavelength of roughly 1,127 nanometers. At energies lower than 1.1 eV, photons do not have enough energy to dislodge electrons. At shorter wavelengths and higher energies, silicon electrons will get energized and current will flow. However, shorter wavelengths and higher photon energies do not correspond with an increase in electrical current. When a photon of higher energy impacts a solar cell, energy above 1.1 eV is given off as heat.

End of Web Info.

Comment from Lambda,

One last question: Is it then correct to believe that the photovoltaic effect is simply a modern more effective version of the photoelectric effect? From what I've read they seem to be very similar.

Comment: The energy required to form an electron-hole pair is significantly lower than the energy required to take an electron out of the material. That is all. In one case you need to take an electron from the valence band to the conduction band, in the other from the valence band to infinity (and beyond!).